# can we use developer provisioning profile to upload (.ipa) to testflight?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning, testflight

I wanted to know that with the provisioning profile of the of iphone developer i was able to generate the (.ipa) for uploading to testflightapp. But it gives me an error in the testflight that "it is invalid (.ipa)" Is that because of the fact the i am using the developer profile and not distribution profile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You **must** use your distribution profile! Also, make sure your ipa has the file [embedded.mobileprovision](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402824-i-get-the-%22invalid-ipa-does-not-contained-provisioned-devices%22-error-when-uploading).

Comment: @MikhaloIvanokov http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

Comment: Hm. I have successfully uploaded ipa and also granted access to other devices, everything configured to a developer profile. However, I seem to be missing some features from the API.

Answer (score 3):

Preparing for testflight contains the following steps

1. Invite teammates with testflight by their email address.
2. In developer.apple.com use 'add devices' and add the device by it's UID
3. Within distribution create a new profisioning profile which contains the devices of the testflight users.
4. Download the new provisioning profile and set it in the XCode build settings -> Code signing Identity
5. Make a new build of your project in XCode with product
6. Upload your newly made .ipa to testflight and set the testflight testers

Your done!

EDIT:

I've you've made a testflight before of your App you can also choose to stop after step 3 and just upload your newly created profile to testflight. (as OneGuyInDc says)

Comment: Regrading step 5
You do not have to rebuild and create a new IPA if you add a new UUID to the distribution profile - you can add the UUID to the profile - save the profile and then upload the profile to Testflight.

Answer (score 2):

That's right yes, it needs to be a distribution one. You'll probably see it complaining about `get-task-allow` being true rather than false or something. I'm not entirely sure why TestFlight bother to check for this, but they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a provisioning profile for distribution.

That said, you don't select it in Xcode. Select "None" for all the provisioning profiles in Xcode.

[image]

Valid still in Xcode 5.11.